# Getting Black Video on YouTube while Capturing Screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using this code to capture screen on iOS but while capturing browser which has YouTube Videos I get black Video

```
        var view = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.Frame.Size);
        view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Frame, true);
        var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

I tried this code to send the webview as a parameter to be captured the view refreshed and the webveiw show progress ring all the time and never reloaded:

```
       public async Task<byte[]> CaptureAsync(Xamarin.Forms.View fView)
    {
        CGRect rect = new CGRect(fView.X, fView.Y, fView.Height, fView.Width);
        var view = ConvertFormsToNative(fView, rect);
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.Frame.Size);
        view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Frame, true);
        var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        using (var imageData = image.AsPNG())
        {
            var bytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            return bytes;
        }
    }
     private UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
    {

        var renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(view);

        renderer.NativeView.Frame = size;

        renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

        renderer.Element.Layout(size.ToRectangle());

        var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;

        nativeView.SetNeedsLayout();

        return nativeView;
    }
```

Comment: did you solve it? I am facing same problem when capturinf screenshot. I am also using xamarin.forms and it shows black image in ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you captured the `RootViewController.View` not the `webview` or something else.

Just make sure that the view (which you want to convert to screenshot ) is the video view (`WebView` or `WKWebvView` or `SFSafariViewController.view`..)

Comment: Because I use Xamarin Forms I tried the code posted in the question to send the Xamarin Forms webview as a parameter and then converted it to native UIView to be captured the view refreshed and the webveiw show progress ring all the time and never reloaded "I updated the post with the new Code"

Comment: I tried this natively also I got black video                                                        `UIWebView view = webview;           
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.Frame.Size);
            view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Frame, true);
            var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();`

Comment: @Ebram Hi , could you share a simple sample for us to reproduce ?

Comment: Xia  https://github.com/EbramSamy/ScreenCapturing          it needs to be tested on actual device it works fine on Simulator ... play YouTube Video and then click Take screenshot ... it will capture everything except the video will be black inside the webview